# Add Image and Caption Text to Three20 Table section using TTSectionedDataSource

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20, sectionheader

I am trying to create table using `TTTableViewController`. I want to display an image in the section header along with some caption text, something similar to what instagram and many other application does. I tried using the sample from `TTNavigatorDemo` to display data from `TTSectionedDatasource`, (I am not sure if this is the right way to do it, please suggest some better way if you know any). It contains section name/headers as regular strings and data as `TTTableViewItem`. I tried implementing `<UITableViewDelegate>` protocol and achieved it using `viewForHeaderInSection` method, now the data is separated from section, Is there any better way using [Three20](http://three20.info) through which I can pass on my Header/Section view and `TableItemView` along in a datasource as it would allow me to implement the `TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate`, which I was not able to implement when implementing the `<UITableViewDelegate>` protocol in my class.

My class declaration right now, looks something like

```
@interface ImageTable : TTTableViewController <UITableViewDelegate> { }
```

I would like to show section headers with image and text like:

[image: Instagram]:

I am currently using the `TTNavigatorCode` to populate the data in my
Table which is:

```
   self.dataSource = [TTSectionedDataSource dataSourceWithObjects:
                               @"Food"
                               [TTTableViewItem itemWithText:@"Porridge" URL:@"tt://food/porridge"],
                               [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Bacon & Eggs" URL:@"tt://food/baconeggs"],
                               [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"French Toast" URL:@"tt://food/frenchtoast"],
                               @"Drinks",
                               [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Coffee" URL:@"tt://food/coffee"],
                               [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Orange Juice" URL:@"tt://food/oj"],
                               @"Other",
                               [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Just Desserts" URL:@"tt://menu/4"],
                               [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Complaints" URL:@"tt://about/complaints"],
                               @"Other",
                               [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Just Desserts" URL:@"tt://menu/4"],
                               [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Complaints" URL:@"tt://about/complaints"],
                               nil];
```

I was able to make something similar by implementing the method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return myCustomView;    
}
```

But since my data is coming from the Model Class and I want my generate views and add them to datasource in a formatted way. I would like to know if there is a way using Three20 through which I specify an Array of my data for sections and another array for corresponding data under the sections?

Your help is highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Put your `TTTableview` as `TTTableViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {...}`than in loadView put : `self.tableView.delegate=self;` after that implement `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Create Delegate  FOOTableDelegate.h

```
@interface FOOTableDelegate : TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate 
{

}

- (UIView*) createHeaderView:(FOODataSource *)fDataSource forSectionID:(NSString *)secID;

@end
```

## In FOOTableDelegate.m file

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    if (tableView.style == UITableViewStylePlain) 
        {
        if ([tableView.dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:)]) 
                {
            NSString* title = [tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
            if (title.length > 0) 
                        {
                UIView* header = [_headers objectForKey:title];

                if (nil != header)
                                {
                    header.alpha = 1;

                } 
                                else 
                                {
                    if (nil == _headers) 
                                        {
                        _headers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                    }

                    header = [self createHeaderView:tableView.dataSource forSectionID:title];
                    [_headers setObject:header forKey:title];
                }
                return header;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UIView*) createHeaderView:(FeedDataSource *)fDataSource forSectionID:(NSString *)secID
{

     //do some code for header View

    return View;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //return height for the Section Header
    return height;
}
```

This will help you to solve your problem